# Compiler generates class for purely static method body

Tags: c#, lambda, roslyn

Consider this C# code

```
using System;

public class _
{
    private static int STAT = 9;

    private int INST = 7;

    private void Run(int arg)
    {
        X(() => STAT * STAT);

        X(() => STAT * INST);

        X(() => INST * STAT);

        X(() => INST * INST);
    }

    public void X<T>(Func<T> getValue) {}
}
```

According to https://sharplab.io/ the compiler generates the following code (reduced to the relevantparts).

```
    [Serializable]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

        public static Func<int> <>9__2_0;

        internal int <Run>b__2_0()
        {
            return STAT * STAT;
        }
    }

    private void Run(int arg)
    {
        X(<>c.<>9__2_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__2_0 = <>c.<>9.<Run>b__2_0));
        X(<Run>b__2_1);
        X(<Run>b__2_2);
        X(<Run>b__2_3);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private int <Run>b__2_1()
    {
        return STAT * INST;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private int <Run>b__2_2()
    {
        return INST * STAT;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private int <Run>b__2_3()
    {
        return INST * INST;
    }
}
```

Notice that the first lambda, which is basically static, gets a class generated, while the others have a generated method.
Why does'nt the compiler generate a static method in that case?

It gets even weirder when you add those lines

```
X(() => arg * STAT * STAT);

X(() => arg * STAT * INST);

X(() => arg * INST * STAT);

X(() => arg * INST * INST);
```

Then it generates every lamnbda into a single class but the pure static one still makes an exception and has its own class.

```
private void Run(int arg)
{
    <>c__DisplayClass2_0 <>c__DisplayClass2_ = new <>c__DisplayClass2_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass2_.<>4__this = this;
    <>c__DisplayClass2_.arg = arg;
    X(<>c.<>9__2_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__2_0 = <>c.<>9.<Run>b__2_0));
    X(<>c__DisplayClass2_.<Run>b__1);
    X(<>c__DisplayClass2_.<Run>b__2);
    X(<>c__DisplayClass2_.<Run>b__3);
    X(<>c__DisplayClass2_.<Run>b__4);
    X(<>c__DisplayClass2_.<Run>b__5);
    X(<>c__DisplayClass2_.<Run>b__6);
    X(<>c__DisplayClass2_.<Run>b__7);
}
```

What is the reason behind this special treatment of the pure static lambda?

Comment: Just my 2 cents: If i remember right this happens because of the fact that there would be no place to store the delegate structure generated that prevents re usage. A Purely static delegate will be stored inside your scope(class) as another class so it could be reused. 
*Most bit of reason i remember*: Re usability and also the compatibility of the Stack to pre roslyn compilers (and 3rd party tools) should be preserved.

But ... don`t quote me. Ask the guys at the rosyln repro on githit directly.